# How can someone run a program under Windows 95 Mode when one is running Windows XP under virtual PC Mode on Windows 7 Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7

The Compatibility Mode feature is greyed out under virtual PCs...

One can directly run a program under Windows 95 mode in Windows 7 Ultimate, but this doesn't work for a lot of Windows 95 programs that do work on WinXP.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Can you post a screenshot of the VM?

Comment: Okay I'll do that in a few minutes

Comment: It's not greyed out because of Virtual PC. It is greyed out because the program is being accessed over the network, as your own screenshot says. (*XP Mode* uses a special network provider for accessing the host's files.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t have Windows 7 or XP Mode on hand at the moment, so I can’t give explicit instructions, but I can advise you on a few tests to perform and steps to take.

First, try creating a shortcut to the `setup.exe` file on the desktop of the virtual machine, bring up the *Properties* dialog and see if the compatibility tab is enabled. If so, then set it and run the installer from the shortcut.

If it is not, test if compatibility-mode works for local files. That is, simply copy `\\tsclient\C\Math Invaders Install\setup.exe` to the desktop, then bring up the *Properties* dialog and check if the *Compatibility* tab is enabled.

If not, then we’ll need to think up some other tests or try to find out if (for some reason) compatibility is not supported in XP mode.

If it *is* enabled, then the problem is indeed that compatibility is [not supported for remote files](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/compatibility-mode-greyed-out-on-exe-that-is-on-a/03c93e47-3d66-485c-b28f-73d06bc793d5). In that case, you will have to try to trick/force Windows into doing it:

1. Set the compatibility-mode as desired for the local `setup.exe` (the one you copied to the desktop)
2. Open the registry editor (`regedit.exe`) and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`
3. Select the *Edit* menu and then `New->String`
4. Replace `New Value #1` with `\\tsclient\C\Math Invaders Install\setup.exe`
5. Copy the contents of the local `setup.exe` entry to the new one (depending on which options you selected, it may only be `WIN95`)
6. Close the registry editor and bring up the *Properties* dialog for the remote copy of `setup.exe` and see if it has the right settings (regardless of if it is grayed or not)

If it is, try running the setup program. Hopefully it will work (an unpleasant manual work-around, but at least the hack works).

If it doesn’t work, then your best bet will be to simply copy the whole `\\tsclient\C\Math Invaders` folder to the VM (e.g., the desktop), install from there, then delete the installation files from the VM (don’t forget to set the compatibility-mode for the installed *Math Invaders* executable if necessary).

Comment: +1, a much more complete answer than mine.

Comment: Wow - that definitely worked. Thanks very much! (though now there's the issue that Windows XP mode doesn't support Direct X :p)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that is a much more involved issue. For that, your best bet is to use full, supported VM software like VirtualBox. Oh, and which part worked?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this out in XP mode on Win7 x64.  When I tick the box above the greyed out item, I can select the type of compatibility just fine.  So, the greying out of the checkbox *shouldn't* be happening.  You could try editing the registry directly to enable compatibility mode, by following [these instructions](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-server-2008/howto-fix-compatibility-mode-grayed-out-on-vista-windows-2008-server/) (inside the XP mode VM), or it may be worth uninstalling and reinstalling XP mode from "Programs and Settings".  (This will lose any customisation you've already made to your XP mode VM though.)

Also, compatibility mode is greyed out for 64 bit programs because there is no backward compatibility for these.  This is unlikely to be your problem though.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that this box is uncheckable (i.e. it's greyed out).

Comment: -1 for not even looking at OP's picture. *answered 24 mins ago* vs. *edited 2 hours ago*, so it's not like it wasn't there for looking at.

Comment: Nice assumptions you have there.  The picture is small and I have poor eyesight.  I *thought* it looked the same as on my screen.

Comment: Have altered the answer to contain some hopefully helpful suggestions.

Comment: @Christi CTRL + Mouse Wheel Up: the picture is high resolution, just resized.

Answer (score 0):

For me this comment of user1686 Mar 25 '12 at 15:13 worked like a charm:

> It's not greyed out because of Virtual PC. It is greyed out because the program is being accessed over the network, as your own screenshot says. (XP Mode uses a special network provider for accessing the host's files.)

So I copied the file from shared folder to virtual box's Windows XP desktop, opened the properties and could thick the box "Compatibility mode".

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.